# Special Characters (particularly ?) not working in custom redirect URL field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I'm attempting to redirect to a page with a question mark in the URL so that I can track submissions in Google Analytics. A form submission would ideally redirect to http://example.com/application-completed?abc123 (abc123 being a replacement token taken from a hidden field in the form, an ID if you like).

The issue I've got is that the question mark causes the URL to cut off at that point, so the above example simply redirects to http://example.com/application-completed. If I replace the ? with a /, the redirect works so I know the replacement token is correct. The reason I need to use the ? is that I have created an 'application-completed' page that uses a custom template so going to application-completed/abc123 gives me a 404.

I'm guessing it is something to do with valid_url? Any help would be much appreciated. I'm a front end dev with little knowledge of altering Drupal beyond the standard backend so please forgive me if the question seems basic.

Comment: Did you mean to put a ? instead of a & in the url in your post? How are you redirecting the form? How is the for generated?

Comment: I did, thanks for pointing that out. I've edited now.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, you want to track if a user submitted the form. in drupal 7 you can edit the **webform-confirmation.tpl.php** and edit some **GA-script**.

In webform-confirmation.tpl.php add this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
ga('send', 'pageview', '/#any-track-id-you-want-to-use');
// ]]></script>
```

now you have to edit your **html.tpl.php** (where you include your GA-script) and add these inside of your script:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash);
```

i hope this helps you.

Comment: That's not the functionality that I'm after unfortunately as I need to use a replacement token in the URL and the replacement token is dynamic in that it can change depending on what node I'm on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to enable special characters in the URL try installing the [Transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module. The project page says so

> it takes Unicode text and tries to represent it in US-ASCII characters (universally displayable, unaccented characters) by attempting to transliterate the pronunciation expressed by the text in some other writing system to Roman letters.

As a rule of thumb, any non alphanumeric character should be URL encoded.  This of course applies to characters that are to be interpreted as is (ie: is not intend to have special meanings) .  In such cases, there's no harm in URL-Encoding the character,  even if the character actually does not need  to be URL-Encoded.

If you don't want to URL encode those special characters go to modules->overlay and uninstall the overlay module